# How to return/convert Flow<Boolean> from Boolean in Kotlin Coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have an Android library in which I am listening to network changes, what I want to do is, observe those changes using Flow/launch of coroutines

This is my NetworkReceiver, which lets me know when there are changes in the connection

I have taken a variable `isNetworkConnectionActive` which is set to false on the `init` of the library and is set true false in the below function based on the network changes

```
class ConnectionChangeReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
        if(isNetworkConnectionActive(context)) {
            OfflineDataLibrary.isNetworkConnectionActive = true
            Toast.makeText(context, "isNetworkConnectionActive - YES", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else {
            OfflineDataLibrary.isNetworkConnectionActive = false
            Toast.makeText(context, "isNetworkConnectionActive - NO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    }

    fun isNetworkConnectionActive(context: Context?): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager = context?.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        var isConnectionActive = false
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            val nw      = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false
            val actNw = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(nw) ?: return false
            return when {
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
                else -> false
            }
        } else {
            val nwInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo ?: return false
            return nwInfo.isConnected
        }
    }
}
```

OfflineDataLibrary which has `isNetworkConnectionActive`

```kotlin
object OfflineDataLibrary {
    lateinit var context: Context
    var isNetworkConnectionActive: Boolean = false
    fun init(ctx: Context) {
        context = ctx.applicationContext
        val offlineDataChangeListener = OfflineDataChangeListener()
        offlineDataChangeListener.observeOfflineDataChanges()
    }
}
```

Now I want to listen to changes happening on `isNetworkConnectionActive` variable using a `Flow`
****HERE I HAVE A TYPE MISMATCH, I WANT TO RETURN FLOW OF BOOLEAN BUT BUT I AM RETURNING BOOLEAN.***

```
  fun getNetworkAvailability(): Flow<Boolean> {

        return OfflineDataLibrary.isNetworkConnectionActive
    }
```

I can access the above function and listen to changes like this

```
  fun getIsNetworkAvailable() {
        launch {
        OfflineDatabaseManager.getInstance(app.applicationContext).getNetworkAvailability().collect {
                //DO something
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I convert `Boolean` to `Flow<Boolean>`?

If you think there can be any other way to subscribe to changes happening on the network, please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `StateFlow` you don't have to use a `LiveData` or a `ConflatedChannel` and you don't even have to convert a `Channel` into a `Flow`:

```
class ConnectionChangeReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {

    private val _networkConnectionActivated = MutableStateFlow(false) //An initial value is required
    val networkConnectionActivated: StateFlow<Boolean>
        get() = _networkConnectionActivated

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
        _networkConnectionActivated.value = isNetworkConnectionActive(context)
    }

    fun isNetworkConnectionActive(context: Context?): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager = context?.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        var isConnectionActive = false
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            val nw      = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false
            val actNw = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(nw) ?: return false
            return when {
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
                else -> false
            }
        } else {
            val nwInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo ?: return false
            return nwInfo.isConnected
        }
    }
}
```

All you have to do is collect its value from outside the class. Remember it's conflated so observers won't be notified until its value changes:

```
myConnectionChangeReceiver.networkConnectionActivated
    .collect {  isNetworkConnectionActive ->
        //Do something here
    }
```

Don't forget to stop all the observers when required by cancelling all the coroutines where they're running on.

You can find `StateFlow` official documentation [here](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/).

Comment: Hi thank you for this, I cannot access `MutableStateFlow` and `StateFlow`. what should I import to access these?

Comment: sorry I did not coroutines imported, got it now. will try it

Comment: @BRDroid No problem. kotlin-coroutines 1.3.6 or later is required in case of someone else doesn't know.

Comment: Hello, I tried your code, and a question I have, In another class if i write a function like this `  suspend fun observeNetworkChanges() {
         var connectionChangeReceiver = ConnectionChangeReceiver()

        connectionChangeReceiver.networkConnectionActivated
            .collect {  isNetworkConnectionActive ->
                //Do something here
                Toast.makeText(OfflineDataLibrary.context, "I am a suspend fun observing net changes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
    }` I do have to call it once from the init function to start listening?

Comment: @DRDroid I would inject the `ConnectionChangeReceiver` object and I would consume changes like this: `fun observeNetworkChanges = myCoroutineScope.launch {
        connectionChangeReceiver.networkConnectionActivated
            .collect { isNetworkConnectionActive ->
                //Do something here
            }
    }`. You can call that method whenever you want. If you think during `init` is right then do it that way. Having multiple observers is even possible. Just remember to stop them all by cancelling `myCoroutineScope` or individually, that depends on your implementation.

Comment: Hello @Glenn Sandoval, I tried your example completely but I am unable to listen to changes happening on the other class where I want to listen to changes. This is the function I call on the Init of the library, when the network changes are made `onReceive` and `_networkConnectionActivated.value` are set correctly but the following function is not listen to.

Comment: fun observeNetworkChanges() {
        launch {
            var connectionChangeReceiver = ConnectionChangeReceiver()
            connectionChangeReceiver.networkConnectionActivated
                .collect {  isNetworkConnectionActive ->
                    //Do something here
                    Toast.makeText(OfflineDataLibrary.context, "I am a suspend fun observing net changes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    Log.d("offlineDatabaseLib", "I am a suspend fun observing net changes")
                }
        }
    }

Comment: The above function is called from my init block which gets initialised onCreate of my android priject

object OfflineDataLibrary {
    lateinit var context: Context
    //var isNetworkConnectionActive: Boolean = false
    fun init(ctx: Context) {
        context = ctx.applicationContext
        val offlineDataChangeListener = OfflineDataChangeListener()
        offlineDataChangeListener.observeOfflineDataChanges()
        offlineDataChangeListener.observeNetworkChanges()
    }
}

Comment: @BRDroid It's hard to know, it could be anything. If `observeNetworkChanges` is not getting called then check `observeOfflineDataChanges` method call, it might be stuck right there.

Comment: Hi I think it was the object creation within the launch. When I moved the code to the android project which has one reference to library it worked fine. Thank you so much. My next task would be to link fb change and network change work together to return lost of data from data base. Thank you for being very helpful.

Comment: Sanoval, thank you for your help on this. I have another query about combining two Flow related data, I have tried my best to explain what I wanted to do in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62351191/combining-two-listeners-kotlin-coroutines It would be very helpful if you can suggest

Answer (score 1):

`Flow` is supposed to be self-contained stream of data.

You can only send data through flow builder while initialization. You cannot randomly emit data to it from outside the builder.

So, for your purpose, you can use `LiveData` instead of Flow.

Just create an instance of `MutableLiveData<Boolean>` and return it inside `getNetworkAvailability()`.

Whenever network state changes just call `setValue()` with value (or `postValue()` if in background thread) to send latest state.

and on the other side observe the changes using `networkLiveData.observe()` and use the changes to do stuff.

Besides LiveData, you can also use ConflatedBroadcastChannel.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @BRDroid No problem. Let me know if need any further help.

Comment: I read about Live data but LiveData requires a ViewModel right, in my library I donot have ViewModels

Comment: @BRDroid Not necessarily. But you need a lifeCycleOwner to observe it though. Forgot to mention, if what you want is just Network status, try NetworkCallback - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback

Answer (score -1):

I think you need a [`Channel`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/channels.html), then you can convert it to a `Flow` using extension functions [`receiveAsFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/receive-as-flow.html) and [`consumeAsFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/consume-as-flow.html) (at the moment of writing this answer it is an experimental feature). So in an abstract manner, your code would look like:

```kotlin
class YouClass {
    private val networkConnectionChannel : Channel<Boolean>(Channel.CONFLATED)

    var isNetworkConnected: Boolean
    get
    set {
        field = value
        networkConnectionChannel.sendBlocking(value)
    }

    fun getNetworkConnectionFlow() : Flow<Boolean> =
        networkConnectionChannel.receiveAsFlow()
}
```